# Multithreading problems in WPF application using a barcode scanner

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I am using an MVVM style architecture and the whole application works fine.  But I am introducing a scanner to the app and am now having numerous multithreading issues.  The following is just some pseudocode but is basically how I need it to work:

**View.xaml**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

**View.xaml.cs**

```
class View : UserControl
{
    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
    private Scanner scanner;//this is my scanner, duh

    public ViewModel()
    {
        scanner = new Scanner();
        scanner.ScanEvent += ScanEvent;
        //all this does is when the scanner scans something
        //then it will trigger an event looking for method ScanEvent()
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList{ get; set; }

    public void ScanEvent()
    {
        string strBarcode = scanner.strBarcode;
        MyList.Insert(0, strBarcode);//this is where the error is thrown
    }
}
```

The error that is thrown is `This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.`  The scanner works fine when I set it to one of my objects so I don't understand why I can't do the same with this `ObservableCollection`?  Here is a snippet from my scanner class that deals with the event:

**Scanner.cs**

```
internal class Scanner
{
    public delegate void EventHandler();
    public event EventHandler ScanEvent = delegate { };

    public Scanner()
    {
        m_pCoreScanner.BarcodeEvent += new _ICoreScannerEvents_BarcodeEventEventHandler(OnBarcodeEvent);
        RegisterForEvents();
    }

    public void OnBarcodeEvent(short eventType, ref string scanData)
    {
        strBarcode = GetBarcodeFromXml(scanData);

        ScanEvent();
    }

    //this class is huge, so I only included pertinent code 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception message says, you'll have to update the ObservableCollection in the UI (or Dispatcher) thread, because a UI element's property (`DataGrid.ItemsSource`) is bound to the collection.

Try this:

```
public void ScanEvent()
{
    string strBarcode = scanner.strBarcode;

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        new Action(() => MyList.Insert(0, strBarcode)));
}
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid.  I have quite a few spots that this problem occurs.  Is this the only solution?  I mean is it common practice with WPF to do this?

Comment: There might be other, more tricky solutions. However, this (and of course `BeginInvoke`) is the standard way to update UI elements from non-UI threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid doing Dispatcher.Invoke everywhere when wanting to get back to the UI thread - which I agree is fugly and is not very helpful for testing you could try using Reactive Extensions (Rx .Net).

Using Rx you can handle the event processing in a 'push' manner instead of the standard .Net events way (pull model). This will then allow you to compose LINQ style queries over the event\data and importantly in your case handle the scheduling back onto the dispatcher (UI) thread.

Below is the code above re-written to use Rx instead of the standard .Net event model:

.Net framework version = 4.0 (WPF)
Rx version = 2.0.21103.1

There are newer version of the Rx framework available on nuGet, you will also need to include Rx-WPF if you're going to use them with WPF.

```
internal class Scanner
{
    public IObservable<EventArgs> ScanEvent
    {
        get
        {
            return Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
            h => m_pCoreScanner.BarcodeEvent += h, h => m_pCoreScanner.BarcodeEvent -= h)
            .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel : IDisposable
{
    private Scanner scanner;
    private IDisposable _disposable;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        scanner = new Scanner();
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        _disposable = scanner.ScanEvent
            .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                string strBarcode = scanner.strBarcode;
                MyList.Insert(0, strBarcode);
            });
    }

    public  void Dispose()
    {
        _disposable.Dispose();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

A good place to start with learning Rx is this free online e-book - http://www.introtorx.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you use a framework such as MvvmLight, you could leverage the message mechanisms. You register a handler in your VM and then send the message from your scanner library

http://wbsimms.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-messaging-example/

These messages work across assemblies via a Default singleton, but all depends on whether you're scanner library is customisable.

Comment: Because the message is triggered on one thread and responded to on the UI thread. At least that is what I believe, happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: In the example URL you give the message is published on the UI and subscribed on the UI, there is no context switching going on as far as I can tell...

Comment: The example was to demonstrate the technology, in the answer I explain how to integrate it in this scenario. The fundamental reason for messaging in MVVM is to support view models communicating with out view models without creating a dependency, I would expect that treating the relationship between the scanner class and the view model in the same way, it I would be possible to implement a solution.

Comment: what is the first word in the title?

Comment: I appreciate the lesson in reading. I have provided a viable alternate solution to the question, as requested. As stated, I am happy to be educated if I am wrong = However, I don't think continuing this discussion with you is going to enrich either of our lives or that of the developer who originally had the issue.